# how to declare a boolean and only gives true if the first and the last character is "a"

Tags: java, boolean

Given a string `personName`, I'm trying to create a boolean `condition2` equal to the condition

```
the first or last letter in personName is 'A' (case-insensitive). e.g., 'aha' or 'A'
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
boolean condition2;
if (personName.charAt(0) = "a" || personName.charAt(personName.length()-1) = "a") {
    condition2 = true;
} else {
    condition2 = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use single quote for data type `char`. and convert it to lower case, so that it allow whether it's upper case or lower case.

Also use `==` when comparing if it's equal. this `=` sign, is for assigning value

```
if(Character.toLowerCase(personName.charAt(0)) == 'a' || 
   Character.toLowerCase(personName.charAt(personName.length()-1)) == 'a')
```

it will look like this

```
boolean condition2;
if(Character.toLowerCase(personName.charAt(0)) == 'a' || Character.toLowerCase(personName.charAt(personName.length()-1)) == 'a')
{
    condition2 = true;
}
else{
    condition2 = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way except comparison operator is == and you compare characters, not String.
So right way would be:

```
Character.toLowerCase(personName.charAt(0)) == 'a'
```

See, double equals and single quote.

Answer (score 0):

char type in Java is a character so wouldn't you be looking for something like this?

```
    boolean condition2;
    if((personName.charAt(0) == 'a' || personName.charAt(0) == 'A') && 
(personName.charAt(personName.length()-1) == 'a' || personName.charAt(personName.length()-1) == 'A'))
    {
        condition2 = true;
    }
    else{
        condition2 = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question where first and last character of a String should be 'a'

```
boolean condition1 = false; 
if(personName.charAt(0) == 'a' && personName.charAt(personName.length()-1) == 'a') {
    condition1 = true;
}
```

For your second condition where variable should be true only if age is in the range [18,24]

```
boolean condition2 = false;
if(personAge >=18 && personAge <=24) {
    condition2 = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is circuitous to write

```
boolean b;
if (some boolean expression)
   b = true;
else
   b = false;
```

Much simpler to write

```
boolean b = some boolean expression;
```

For reasons I don't understand, there is a widespread reluctance to write a boolean expression (as distinct from the simple literal values true/false) outside an 'if' statement.

And don't get me started on `if (b == true)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solve in this manner;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    String s = "bsdadasd";
    boolean condition2;

        System.out.println(check(s.toLowerCase().charAt(0),s.toLowerCase().charAt(s.length()-1)));
    }
    public static boolean check(char a,char b){
        return (a == 'a' || b == 'a');
    }
```

You can pass the two characters as parameters for a method where it return `true` or `false`depending on the condition.

Since both characters are irrelevant of its case first made them to lowercase. `toLowerCase()` then passed the char at 0 and char at last.

The `return` statement will return the true or false to you.

And also use `==` to check if similar `=` means assigning.